# Trickling down an interruption (kill -15 or 9) signal (Ctrl + C) from ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor --> ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have been reading a lot on this but I am not sure what's the most elegant way of handling my usecase. I have an application that starts a background scheduled thread using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. This scheduled thread in-turn has an `ExecutorService` of pool size 20. Each new thread submitted to this pool will inturn again have an `ExecutorService` of pool size, lets say 50. The lowest level thread doesn't do much other than looping through some standard tasks, each task taking anywhere from a second to 10 seconds.

As this is a background agent application performing background tasks, We should be able to stop them cleanly any time we want. The problem is I am not sure how to trickle down the an interuption/shutdown signal 3 level down to the lowest thread so I can break out of the loop and shutdown all the threads neatly.

I was looking into `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` but I wasn't exactly sure how it will be useful in my usecase. I was also looking into checking for `isInterrupted()` at the lowest possible Thread level but than I wasn't sure if `Ctrl + C` or `kill -9 / kill -15` command actually is transformed to an interrupted signal inside the application. And if so, how would it trickle down 3 levels of threads, or would I have to manually interrupt each thread inside the `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`.

I am trying to find a solution that is most elegant and safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *interrupted* flag has nothing to do with native OS-level signals sent to the process hosting the JVM. You can set the *interrupted* flag on any thread by calling `thread.interrupt()`.

For your problem I would suggest accumulating all your `ExecutorService`s into a global collection so that you may call `shutdownNow()` on each upon termination. If you use a gentle-enough signal to terminate your process, the shutdown hooks should be executed and there you can try to shut down your executor services. Note, however, that each task you submit must be *interruptible*, which means that it must respoond to the setting of the *interrupted* flag by actually finishing its work. This will not happen implicitly.

I must add that I find your solution with numerous executor services quite odd. A single, properly configured thread pool should be all you need in addition to the scheduled executor.

Comment: interesting .. Any feedback on how I should achieve my usecase from an architectural perspective? I am kind of lost when you say "properly configured"? The idea is: intial pool gets a list of companies. Each company gets a dedicated pool for all it's tasks. I am still coming up with a configuration algorithm to properly manage the resources per company pool. Are you suggesting I should not segregate by company and just pool all tasks into one executor service?

Comment: Usually the executor service is a global resource, used by from all parts of code. The only reason to use more than one is to have differently configured instances. Executors don't belong to domain entities.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the input ! One more follow up question. The lowest level threads. They are already running tasks in a loop, I just have to check for isInterrupted() before next loop iteration starts. did i get that right?

Comment: Yes, if each iteration takes a reasonably short time.